# ¿cómo recargar pagina cuando se redimencione el navegador?

Tags: javascript

el siguiente codigo me funciona perfectamente (es para recargar la pagina al hacer click en el cuerpo de ella):

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].onclick = function () { location.reload() }
```

pero este proximo codigo no me funciona, a pesar de que no hay error de sintaxis:

```
window.onresize = function () { location.reload() }
```

Quiero que me funcione el codigo 2, es decir, quiero que cuando redimencione la pagina ésta se recargue. Cabe señalar que cuando al codigo 2 le pongo un alert dentro de las llaves, funciona perfectamente. Con location no funciona.

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function(e){
    console.log(`width:${screen.width} height:${screen.height}`);
    location.reload();

});

window.onresize= function(e){
    console.log(`width:${screen.width} height:${screen.height}`);
    location.reload();

}
```